# Map jj to <esc> with XVim plugin

Tags: xcode, vim, xvim

XVim claims to read *~/.xvimrc* but I am not seeing any effect. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Here is an example of my *.xvimrc*:

```
nmap jj <esc>
```

I have also tried :

```
imap jj <esc>
```

Comment: Did you `:source .vimrc` while editing the .xvimrc, or restart vim?

Comment: You have already asked the same thing on [xVim's issue tracker](https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim/issues).

Comment: sjas Do you mean ":source .vimrc" in xcode? Or, in the .xvimrc?

Comment: I am aware of that, romainl

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer for your specific case, but if your .xvimrc has:

```
inoremap jk <Esc>
```

This wasn't working for me, and in fact had the unpleasant side effect of slowing down the j key badly when just trying to move the cursor down. Switching to:

```
imap jk <Esc>
```

did fix it for me (Xcode 4.6.3).

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with

`imap jj <Esc>`

using Xcode 4.6.2 and XVim dc470f5 (which is about a month old).

Maybe the Esc is case sensitive?